# How can I declare a variable in C?

Tags: c, string, comparison

I am doing a code for my homework and it needs to ask the person from which continent they are

I have to do it on C and I am just learning this language right now

So, here I got so far

```
printf("Which continent are you from? ");
char continent[10];
scanf("%s",continent);
```

Now I set the different options that the program should look for (I'll only use two for the sake of this example)

```
char America[10];
char Europe[10];
```

Now, here is what I am trying to do:

```
America = (continent == "America" or continent == "america");
Europe = (continent == "Europe" or continent == "europe");
```

I know they are wrong and that that is not the way yo compare strings, but I just want to depict what I am trying to do.

```
if (America or Europe) {
    if(America){
     printf("wc");
    }
    if(Europe){
    printf("toilet");
    }
}
```

So, how can I compare the string and also tell the program that if the string is equal to a certain word, it should go in the "America" or "Europe" variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strcmp()` function. Be sure to `#include <string.h>`.

```
scanf("%s, continent);
if (strcmp(continent, "America") == 0) //if string matches
{
    <do interesting stuff>
}
```

You could also use `strcasecmp()` to do case-insensitive compare. Note that this `strcasecmp()` isn't standard C but `gcc` supports it.
You could also write your own function using `for()` loop to iterate through string and check each character using `if(string1[i] == string2[i]`.